# How to save to Django Model that Have Mulitple Foreign Keys Fields

Tags: django, orm

I have this Model

```
class inventory_transaction(models.Model):    
    stockin = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True,max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    stockout = models.DecimalField(blank=True,null=True,max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    from_container = models.ForeignKey(container_identity)
    staffs = models.ForeignKey(staff_name)
    goods_details = models.ForeignKey(departments)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class meta:
        ordering = ["date"]
        get_latest_by = "date"
```

My Question is

1. How do i save do i save data into it with its multiple foreign keys fields taken care of

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem? is the code you have so far not working? what's wrong with it? (If you get error messages, show them. If the behavior is not as expected, explain what it does now, and how that is different from what you need). Besides, We shouldn't be guessing what variables like staffname and vdataz are. show us a complete code that explains where these vars come from.

Comment: ok i am sorry about that i will now add details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
transaction = inventory_transaction() # read PEP 8 and rename to InventoryTransaction
transaction.staffs = staff_name.objects.create(params)
transaction.goods_details = departmens.objects.create(params)

# other attrs

transaction.save()
```